# page count in jqgrid with server side paging

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, paging

I am implementing server side paging for JQGrid (with MVC4). I am able to make that out. I am not using JQGrid's pager option. Instead I am using custom pager implementation. For that I need to get the total pages returned by server.

I have tried the following:

```
grid.getGridParam('lastpage')  -- always returns 1, which makes sense as I am returning only one page contents to the grid
grid.getGridParam('total')  -- I tried this because I was setting this value in the controller, but it is returning null
grid.getGridParam('records') -- always returns 10, my page size.
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you use `loadonce: true` option in a wrong way. The goal of the option is **client side** paging, sorting and filtering/searching. In case of usage `loadonce: true` option the server have to return **all rows**. In case of usage `loadonce: true` option the values `total`, `records` and `page` will be ignored and the corresponding values will be set based on *total number of items returned from the server*. Because you returned only 10 items (the items of the first page) the values of parameters are exactly like you described in your question. By the way I would recommend you to use `loadonce: true` option if you have not so large dataset (for example 1-10 thousand of rows). The server should return in the case *all* items sorted by the requested parameter (`sidx` and `sord`). One can return just array of all sorted items from the server without any additional information.

By the way the meaning of the page related parameters of jqGrid is the following:

- **page** - the 1-based number of the current page
- **lastpage** - the page number of the last page
- **rowNum** - the page size - the maximal number of records in a page (the last page can contains less records)
- **records** - total records (on all pages) in the grid
- **reccount** - the total number of records displayed in the page (less or equal the page
  size rowNum)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `dataType : "json"` , then you need to set these values in `jsonReader` property of jqGrid ,

```
 $("#gridid").jqGrid({
    ...
       jsonReader : { 
          root: "rows", 
          page: "page", 
          total: "total", 
          records: "records", 
          repeatitems: true, 
          cell: "cell", 
          id: "id",
          userdata: "userdata",
          subgrid: { 
             root:"rows", 
             repeatitems: true, 
             cell:"cell" 
          } 
       },
    ...
    });
```

Which in the end are values sent to server for fetching data's. So if you have to override these value you need to change these values.

So , make sure you are using same values in server side to fetch these values.